# Java - Spring AspectJ AfterThrowing

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

I have a method with following signature

I want to log exception after catching by my point cut, rite now when i execute the code it throws the exception print on the console then comes to my point cut defined method, may be because it is @AfterThoring annotation but there is no @BeforeThrowing annotation available ? please suggest what can i do

```
public void jingleBell(){
        System.out.println("Jingle Bell Job...");
        throw new RuntimeException("test error");
    }
```

and following advice with pointcut

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.dc.lnwsk.adapter.Search.jingleBell())", throwing = "ex")
            public void handleException(Throwable ex){
                    //Log exception
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exceptions are not like `methods` where bye code can be altered(**weaved**) to call a new method before calling the point cut method.

Exceptions are run time phenomenon and JVM doesn't know in advance that some exception is going to be thrown and hence **no @BeforeThrowing**.

if you know your exception scenario up-front then better use `@Before` on the point cut method and handle the exception scenario.